# Read data from XBRL file with vb.net

Tags: xbrl

I state that I don't have much experience with XBRL files.
I need to read some data from an XBRL file using vb.net.
I tried to look for examples but could not find anything clear.
Is there a class that read data from an xbrl file?
The XBRL files that I use are simple, with only the balance sheet and the income statement, I don't need to extract other data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few .NET-friendly XBRL processors available. One possibility is Gepsio. Gepsio is a document object model class library for XBRL documents based on .NET Standard 2.1. It is open source at https://github.com/JeffFerguson/gepsio, a "Getting Started" Wiki at https://github.com/JeffFerguson/gepsio/wiki, and a NuGet package available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gepsio/.

Another popular choice is Arelle. Arelle is a project to provide the XBRL community with an easy to use open source platform for XBRL. It supports XBRL and its extension features in an extensible manner. It does this in a compact yet robust framework that can be used as a desktop application and can be integrated with other applications and languages utilizing its web service. You can find it at https://arelle.org/.

Comment: I had read a few things about GEPSIO, but was unable to find the guide you provided.
I just need to read some data from an xbrl file, with GEPSIO can I do it easily?
Are there any examples?
My application is in ASP.NET VB but I can also program in C #

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the a "Getting Started" Wiki at https://github.com/JeffFerguson/gepsio/wiki?

Comment: I am Gepsio's author. Email the project at gepsioxbrl@outlook.com and I'll see if I can help you directly. Both VB.NET and C# are supported ... but you need to be on .NET Core, not .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you some mouch JeffFerguson, I write you an email. thanks

Comment: I've try to create a new project ASP.NET Core, but when I try to install Nuget GEPSIO or dotnet add package I've receve error: Value cannot be null. <Parameter 'paht1'>...   I have always worked with the framework project, this is the first time that I do a CORE project..

Comment: You may have an issue with NuGet itself rather than Gepsio ... email the project at gepsioxbrl@outlook.com and we can try and get more information together.

Comment: I found another way ... I perform a parse of the data and extrapolate the values that interest me.
Thanks anyway for the support.